# Assigning value to variable in unix

Tags: unix, sed

i have a result.txt file which contains the following entries

**result.txt**

```
136209
136220
136152
136248
136196
136227
136163
136234
136174
136241
136185
135910
```

I am using sed command to extract each ID and write it into file and then assigning to variable.I want it to reduce,i want something like this `value1=$(<sed '1 ! d' result.txt)` but it is giving me error as ./test.sh: line 19: sed: No such file or directory.

Comment: Are you sure about the IO redirection? `<` seems incorrect.

Comment: before this i used to do like....sed '1 ! d' result.txt >> d1.txt  and then value1=$(<d1.txt) and was working fine for me. So  i though it should work in the same manner for me.Any suggestion?

Comment: try `sed '1 ! d' result.txt` this randomly and worked for me....dont know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment first:

```
value1=$(<d1.txt)
```

would read the file `d1.txt` into the variable `value1`.

The `$(...)` form is used for command substitution and `<` makes the shell look for a file `sed`.  Instead say:

```
value1=$(sed '1 ! d' result.txt)
```